# Trying to form a half triangle using a for loop, nothing is printing out

Tags: java, netbeans

This is a practice exam question I was given to study for my java exam approaching...I was given the main method and cannot change the input, only alter the two other methods and their code. I need to print out

```
     &
    &&
   &&&
  &&&&
 &&&&&
&&&&&&
```

I think I have written my for loop wrong to create the blank spaces, I cannot seem to get this write with the main method I have been give, any ideas?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 6;
    char c = '&';
    for (int i = 1; i < size + 1; i++) {
        drawBlanks(size, size - i);
        drawChars(size, size - i, c);
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();

}

public static void drawChars(int size, int i, char c) {

    for (int j = size; j < 1; j--) {
        System.out.print(c);
    }

}

public static void drawBlanks(int size, int i) {

    for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in this loop :

```
for(int j = size; j < 1; j--)
```

Instead change it to :

```
for (int j = size; j > i; j--) {
//-------------------^_^
```

> `j` should be > to `i` not `j` < to `1`

Comment: ohh yep I see that now, I must have made a typo, thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution within one loop:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rowCount = 10;
        int whiteSpaceCount = rowCount - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++) {
                char ch = ' ';
                if (j >= whiteSpaceCount)
                    ch = '&';
                System.out.print(ch);
            }
            System.out.println();
            whiteSpaceCount = rowCount - (i + 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `j < 1;` to `j > 1;`, After that your output will be,

**Output:**

```
      &&&&&
     &&&&&
    &&&&&
   &&&&&
  &&&&&
 &&&&&
```

To get your expected output change `j > 1` to `j > i`.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            int size = 6;
            char c = '&';
            for (int i = 1; i < size + 1; i++) {
                drawBlanks(size, size - i);
                drawChars(size, size - i, c);
                System.out.println();
        }
    System.out.println();

}

public static void drawChars(int size, int i, char c) {

    for (int j = size; j > i; j--) {
        System.out.print(c);
    }

}

public static void drawBlanks(int size, int i) {

    for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
      &
     &&
    &&&
   &&&&
  &&&&&
 &&&&&&
```